# Dependency injection через метод в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, шаблоны-проектирования

Существует ли в Laravel, возможность внедрить зависимость через метод?
Например, у меня есть контроллер который реализует интерфейс `DoctrineWorkable`:

```
interface DoctrineWorkable {
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $manager);
}

trait EntityManagerTrait {
   protected $manager;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        // Еще какая-та работа с $manager
    }
}

class TestController implements DoctrineWorkable {
    use EntityManagerTrait;
}
```

Как в сервис контейнере можно внедрить зависимость, используя метод `setEntityManager` ? Чтобы получилось что-то вроде такого:

```
if ($class instanceof DoctrineWorkable) {
    $class->setEntityManager(new EntityManager());
}
```

Comment: Необязательные зависимости вещь редкая, обычно всё же через конструктор... и это больше не к laravel, а к самому языку PHP относится. Мне вопрос непонятен: Вы уже всё написали, но видно, что-то не нравится, можете разъяснить подробнее? Материал в помощь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24484782/5752652

Comment: @AK зависимость должна внедрятся во все контроллеры которые реализуют интерфейс EntityManager. Во втором куске кода, я показал как примерно это должно срабатывать, но я не знаю как это можно сделать в laravel. Эта зависимость обязательная

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Зачем вообще нужен интерфейс?

Comment: @PavelMayorov интерфейс - это контракт того, что в контроллер можно передать EntityManager. Конструктор для этого не подходит, просто потому что, в каждом классе придется заново инстанцировать внедряемый объект. Можно конечно создать родительский класс, но мне это не нравится т.к. этот объект будет внедрятся не во все контроллеры т.е. придется создавать два родительских класса (для потомков которые имеют EntityManager и у которых его нет).

Comment: @PavelMayorov Адекватный вариант, который я рассматриваю: написать интерфейс для метода, реализовать метод интерфейса и инстенцируемое поле в трейте, имплементировать интерфейс и подключить трейт в нужном классе.